# SPARQL Construct query Segmentation

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia, linked-data

I run a SPARQL construct query on DBpedia endpoint. The query is for getting all the information describing all movies:

```
construct
{
    ?s ?p ?o
}
where
{
    ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film>.
{
  SELECT ?s ?p ?o
  {
       ?s ?p ?o
  } 
  group by ?s ?p 
}


}
```

The query works fine. The problem is DBpedia stops it at 10.000. I tried to make the offset 0 but it does make any difference. Also, I don't think chrome would support to display a million triple. Therefore, I was thinking if there is a solution, or a tip, so I can retrieve the data by segments, meaning I start from where I stopped previously.

Comment: What is the idea of the sub-query? Just to understand what you wanted to achieve and maybe help you understanding why it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AKSW The only reason why I used the subquery is to be able to use group by. And the reason I wanted to use group by ,specifically there, is because I wanted to get all the subject with all their predicates and all the objects of all the predicates. 

Anyway, retrieving all the data about movies from DBpedia was not a good idea cause they stop the offset at 40000. I found a very efficient and fast, yet light, data format, called RDF HDT. And the entire DBpedia RDF dump was amongst the datasets available in this format.

Comment: In your question you didn't talk about grouping. And in your sub-query you're grouping by `?s` and `?p` but you select `?o` as a simple variable which is not valid SPARQL.

Comment: @AKSW well it got me the result I needed. That's all that matters really. The question was not about the accuracy of the query, it was about getting all the results from DBpedia. and because the latter stops the query at 10.000, I wanted to continue from where it was stopped. The answer is simple: I didn't know the role of offset. And even after I knew the role of "offset", it didn't help me, becuase DBpedia stops the offset at 40.000. Therefore, I decided to download the entire DBpedia RDF dump.

Comment: Not DBpedia stopped, but Virtuoso has some strange limit which can be worked around by using a sub-select. But again, the grouping doesn't make sense. And as I said, it's invalid SPARQL. This won't work on another triple store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.  You can also simplify your query significantly:

```
construct
{
   ?s ?p ?o
}
where
{
   ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> .
   ?s ?p ?o
} ORDER BY ?s ?p ?o
  OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1000
```

Then change the `OFFSET` for each "segment".